# chiba xforms, and using a changed value in conditional expression

Tags: xforms

There is a code working with appache tomcat and chiba-3.0.0b2

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xhtml:html xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:xforms="http://www.w3.org/2002/xforms"
    xmlns:events="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events">
<xhtml:head>
```

There i use some instances

```
    <xforms:model>
        <xforms:instance id="xs">
            <xs>
                <x kd="1" name="one"></x>
                <x kd="2" name="two"></x>
                <x kd="3" name="three"></x>
                <!-- ... -->
            </xs>
        </xforms:instance>
        <xforms:instance id="vars">
            <vrbls>
                <vrbl>1</vrbl>
            </vrbls>
        </xforms:instance>
    </xforms:model>
</xhtml:head>
<xhtml:body>
    <xforms:switch>
        <xforms:case id="setval">
```

pressing to a trigger, it shows a onerec-case

```
    <xforms:trigger>
        <xforms:label>View</xforms:label>
        <xforms:label ref="@asutus" />
        <xforms:action events:event="DOMActivate">
            <xforms:setvalue ref="instance('vars')/vrbl" value="2" />
            <xforms:toggle case="onerec" />
        </xforms:action>
    </xforms:trigger>
</xforms:case>
<xforms:case id="onerec">
```

In the output-tag the instance('vars')/vrbl works, shows value 2:

```
    <xforms:output ref="instance('vars')/vrbl" /><br />
```

..but if i want to check, it doesnt work, instance('vars')/vrbl has the old value - 1.

```
            <xforms:itemset nodeset="instance('xs')/x[@kd=instance('vars')/vrbl]">
                Name - <xforms:label ref="@name" />, kd - <xforms:label ref="@kd" />
            </xforms:itemset>
        </xforms:case>

    </xforms:switch>
</xhtml:body>
</xhtml:html>
```

How to use changed note's value in the condition expression [@kd=instance('vars')/vrbl], that it works?
Thank you.

Comment: It looks like a problem with Chiba. Have you tried to use a more updated processor like XSLTForms or betterFORMS?

Comment: Thank you, but instead of xforms:itemset should to be xforms:group.